# How do I use an NSProgressIndicator as the view of an NSToolbarItem and have it show in the customisation sheet?

Tags: cocoa, macos, nstoolbar, nsprogressindicator, nstoolbaritem

I have an `NSToolbar` set up in my app. It was created in IB. One of the toolbar items uses a spinner-style `NSProgressIndicator` as its view, the rest are images.

When the toolbar's customization sheet is showing, the spinner does not show in the sheet.

I initially thought that this was because the spinner's `-displayedWhenStopped` was set to `NO`. That's not the case: if I set it to YES, the spinner shows in the toolbar when active, but doesn't show in either the toolbar or the sheet when stopped.

Comment: I definitely can't reproduce this — if displayedWhenStopped is true, it's displayed in both places whether active or inactive.  The only thing I can think of is it's being programmatically hidden when inactive, but I know you'd know the effect that would have...

Comment: I concur with Brock, I can't reproduce it either, it works fine for me.

Comment: @Fraser: Do you have any code you could post for setting up the progress indicator besides what you've done in IB?  I can't reproduce it, like the fellow commentors before me.

Comment: IIRC, the toolbar item in the customization sheet is actually just an archived object.  When it's dragged off the sheet to an actual toolbar at runtime, a new object is created based on the archive.  Thus, the item in the toolbar and on the customization sheet are not the same.  Make sure in *IB* that the properties for the item on the customization panel are correct to enable the spinner to display always.